# Can extensionality and separative-reflection interpret all rules of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Language: first order logic with equality, with additional primitives of membership $\in$ and a constant symbol $V$ standing for the class of all sets.

**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

**Reflection:** if $\varphi$ is a formula in $\mathcal L(=,\in)$, and if $\psi$ is a formula in which $y$ is not free, then all set closures of: $$ \exists x (\varphi) \to  \forall \vec{c} \  \exists x \big[\varphi\wedge \exists y \in V \ y=\{z \in x| \psi\} \big]\;; $$ are axioms.

It's nice to know that just these two axioms can interpret the whole of ZFC, since it straightfowardly prove all axioms of [K(W)](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/TalkAxiomSetThy-ts05xn.pdf) theory (see page 3).

It's known that ZFC can interpret all *set* statements of [Ackermann's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory) set theory, also this theory does that!  Clearly this theory proves all axioms of Ackermann's set theory except those of foundation and class construction! Now the questions are:

> 1. Can this theory interpret all the rules of Ackermann's set theory including class comprehension as well?
> 2. if we restrict the parameters of $\varphi$ to just two, and change $\vec{c}$ to just $c$, would the resulting theory still interpret ZFC?

Comment: What does "set closure" mean?   Perhaps adding all possible quantifiers of the form $\exists z\in V$? So $\psi$ has 2 kinds of variables, those that you call $c$ and those that I call $z$ here?

Comment: @Goldstern yes those bounded ($\in V$) quantified $z$ variables occur at the beginning of the statement (before the first  $\exists x$), and they are what I meant by *set* closures. $\psi$ might have the $z$'s free in them, or both the $z$ and $c$ variables, or non of them. It important to realized that the $c$ string of variables is unbounded! However the parameters of $\varphi$ are only the $z$ variables, i.e. all of them are bounded in $V$.